# ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception

Tags: jenkins

I have performed a Junit test successfully from eclipse.
So i wanted to execute the same test cases from Jenkins.
For that i have written the build.xml (ant build).

```
<path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="lib\junit-4.12-javadoc.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib\junit-4.12-sources.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib\junit-4.12.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib\ojdbc14.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib\oraclejdbc.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib\testng-6.8.5.jar" />
    <pathelement location="bin" />
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <javac classpath="classpath" includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="bin" includes="**/*.java" verbose="true">
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="run_tests" depends="compile">

    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="false" showoutput="yes">
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="false" />
        <test name="om.wipro.TestDbUpdates" />
        <test name="om.wipro.TestExample" />

        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib\junit-4.12-javadoc.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib\junit-4.12-sources.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib\junit-4.12.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib\ojdbc14.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib\oraclejdbc.jar" />
            <pathelement location="lib\testng-6.8.5.jar" />
            <pathelement location="bin" />
        </classpath>

    </junit> 
</target>
```

My problem is that, the execution from Jenkins is not successful. Build is successful(from both eclipse and Jenkins) though test cases are failing.
How to get rid of the following error?

ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
hudson.AbortException:

Regards,
Sharon M P

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket about this error:

> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24946

If you are using Jenkins version "V1.582", they recommend to **upgrade to the latest version to solve this issue**.

You can check your jenkins version at the bottom/right of the web page.